# link.exe, choosing 64-bit or 32-bit version of Kernel32.lib

Tags: assembly, linker

I am trying to compile and link 32 bit program in 64 bit Windows.
I compiled my program with nasm

```
nasm -f win32 test.asm
```

It is compiled successfully. But when i try to link with link.exe

```
link /entry:start /subsystem:console test.obj Kernel32.lib
```

or

```
link /machine:x86 /entry:start /subsystem:console test.obj Kernel32.lib
```

it gives me this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64\Kernel32.lib : warnin
g LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

but when i write the absolute path of 32bit version of Kernel32.lib it links successfully. I think i should add the location of 32bit Kernel32.lib as path variable to somewhere or i should use a switch but i could not find it.

Is there any way to link without writing absolute path ?

Comment: Use `/libpath` to set the path?

Comment: Yes it works but i am trying to give this info to linker permanently. (As environmental variable). I mean linker must understand that .obj file is 32 bit and it must look up for 32 bit versions of libraries. I don't understand why this is happening on my computer. VS and Windows are same with other computers but it's only happening to me. And i am sure i did not change the linker config on other projects.(I've also checked .obj files headers with dumpbin and they are 32bit.)

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into the question.  Your comment on the accepted answer is the only place that comment belongs.

Comment: okey, I re-edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be running the linker (and other SDK tools) from a command prompt that has been properly set up with the correct environment variables. Then you will not have this problem.

The simplest way to do this is to run the provided batch files. `vcvarsall.bat` is the master one, use it with a single argument specifying the type of build environment you want to use. Either `x86` for 32-bit, `amd64` for 64-bit builds using the 64-bit toolchain, or `x86_amd64` for 64-bit builds using the 32-bit toolchain (the 64-bit on 32-bit cross-compiler). Alternatively, you can use the individual batch files, `vcvars32.bat`, `vcvars64.bat`, and `vcbarsx86_amd64.bat`.

You can go through these files yourself and see what environment variables they set up, but it is honestly not worth the time reverse engineering the setup that they do. The relevant portion is setting an environment variable `%WindowsSdkDir%` to the root directory of the Windows SDK installation, and then using that to set:

1. `PATH` to include the appropriate `bin` subdirectory, containing the tools, including link.exe. For x86 and x86_amd64, that is just `bin`. For amd64, it is the `bin\x64` subdirectory.
2. `INCLUDE` to the appropriate `include` subdirectory containing the header files (this is the same for all build types).
3. `LIB` to the appropriate `lib` subdirectory containing the linker dynamic stubs. For x86, this is just `lib`. For amd64 and x86_amd64, it is the `lib\x64` subdirectory.

The one you are apparently missing is the last one. The linker is not looking in the correct directory for the LIB files. It doesn't do it automatically based on the `machine` switch. It has no idea how you have configured your build system or where you have installed the SDK files. Use the batch files to get it all set up correctly with minimal fuss.

Comment: Sorry for the late respond. I checked all environment variables and their usage in vcvarxxx.bat files as you said.They all seemed correct to me. Actually they were all correct :). The mistake is (I am ashamed to say this) that I was using VC2015 x64 CP :)